# Set environment variable in tox that deps require

Tags: python, tox

One of the required Python package needs to be compiled with having a specific environment variable set. I looked at tox documentation either `PASSENV` or `setenv` only impacts the execution of tests `commands`. What can I do? Anything I misunderstand? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution without the need to handle environment variables, that is using `--install-option` of `pip`, for example, `pip install --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl`, which passes `--with-openssl` to underlying `setup.py install`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to not list the dependency in `deps` but instead install it in `commands` using a command or a shell script of your own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's illuminating for me and I already found a solution eventually.